# Join two columns from different files with awk

Tags: awk

I want to join two columns from two different files using awk. These files look like (A, B, C, 0, 1, 2, etc are columns)

file1:

```
A B C D E F
```

fil2:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

And I want to be able to select arbitrary columns on my ouput, something of the form:

Ie, I want the output to be:

```
A C E 4 5
```

I've seen a million answers with the following awk code (and very similar ones), offering no explanation. But none of them address the exact problem I want to solve:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$2;next};{$NF=a[FNR]};1' file2 file1

awk '
    NR==FNR {A[$1,$3,$6] = $0; next} 
    ($1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $3) in A {print A[$1,$2,$3], $4}
' A.txt B.txt
```

But none of them seem to do what I want and I am not able to understand them.

So, how can I achieve the desired output using awk? (and please, offer an explanation, I want to actually learn)

Note: 
I know I can do this using something like

```
paste <(awk '{print $1}' file1) <(awk '{print $2}' file2)
```

As I said, I'm trying to learn and understand awk.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to get from the two files.... can you add  desired output pls?

Comment: It is there. Sorry if it wasn't very clear. I've edited the question (the output I want is A C E 4 5 where A, B, C... 0, 1, 2... are column.

Comment: by join do you mean paste the columns side by side based on row index?  For joining you need key values to match, which is absent in you sample input files.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays and ARGIND:

```
$ awk -v flds='1 1 1 3 1 5 2 5 2 6' '
    BEGIN{ nf = split(flds,o) }
    { f[ARGIND][1]; split($0,f[ARGIND]) }
    NR!=FNR { for (i=2; i<=nf; i+=2) printf "%s%s", f[o[i-1]][o[i]], (i<nf?OFS:ORS) }
' file1 file2
A C E 4 5
```

The "flds" string is just a series of `<file number> <field number in that file>` pairs so you can print the fields from each file in whatever order you like, e.g.:

```
$ awk -v flds='1 1 2 2 1 3 2 4 1 5 2 6' 'BEGIN{nf=split(flds,o)} {f[ARGIND][1]; split($0,f[ARGIND])} NR!=FNR{for (i=2; i<=nf; i+=2) printf "%s%s",f[o[i-1]][o[i]], (i<nf?OFS:ORS)}' file1 file2
A 1 C 3 E 5
$ awk -v flds='2 1 1 2 2 3 1 4 2 5' 'BEGIN{nf=split(flds,o)} {f[ARGIND][1]; split($0,f[ARGIND])} NR!=FNR{for (i=2; i<=nf; i+=2) printf "%s%s",f[o[i-1]][o[i]], (i<nf?OFS:ORS)}' file1 file2
0 B 2 D 4
```